# How to get region of S3 bucket with Bucket name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am working on project with Amazon S3 and I am using AWS SDK 2 to interact with S3.
I have many old buckets created into my S3 account and now I want to change the code of authentication and setting the ACL.

I have created S3Client :

```
AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    ACCESS_KEY,
                    SECRET_KEY);
            S3ClientBuilder s3ClientBuilder = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds));
            if (regionString != null) {
                Region region = Region.of(regionString);
                s3ClientBuilder.region(region);
            }           
            S3Client s3Client = s3ClientBuilder.build();
            return s3Client;
```

Default region I have given is : US_EAST_1.

If I do not specify this region then it showing the creation dates of bucket wrong.

Now by using above S3client, I am moving forward and working with ACL :

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetBucketAclRequest getBucketAclRequest =                        

software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetBucketAclRequest.builder().bucket(sbktname).build();
GetBucketAclResponse bucketAcl1 = s3Client.getBucketAcl(getBucketAclRequest);
```

But it throwing issue : **software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'**

My question is that how can I get region from existing s3 client which already created using bucket name only. I do not have bucket object, I have bucket name only.

Using bucket name I tried to get the location but it throwing same issue of region mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you an example in Java, but you need to use `GetBucketLocation` API.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetBucketLocation.html

From the following example look that I am forcing to run the command on `sa-east-1` region but my bucket is located on `us-east-2`.

```
$ aws --region sa-east-1 s3api get-bucket-location --bucket my-bucket
{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-east-2"
}
```

You can see the same behavior from Python SDK

```
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  5 2021, 01:49:30)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='sa-east-1')
>>> s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket='my-bucket')['LocationConstraint']
'us-east-2'
```

Buckets in Region `us-east-1` have a LocationConstraint of `null`.

Comment: Very helpful, though it's truly bizarre that we have to specify a region endpoint when the whole point of the call is to GET the region.  One important thing I noted in doing some testing of my own: some regions where I have no content still let me perform the request, while certain others returned a 403 Forbidden error.  I assume this must have to do with data segregation between certain regions.  The key point is that it seems you cannot simply perform the query against any regionendpoint you want.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that how can I get region from existing s3 client which
> already created using bucket name only. I do not have bucket object, I
> have bucket name only.

You can use [s3api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/#cli-aws-s3api) to get the bucket location e.g. if your bucket name is `abc123`, you can get the location using the following command:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket abc123
```

Check the [`get-bucket-location`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-location.html) documentation page to learn more about it.